# loop through mysql_query and replace value OR 1 query to do work

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I am running a sql query, that pulls the id, catid, name, subof from two tables using inner join.

```
select shop.id, shop.catid, shop.name, shop_cat.catname, shop_cat.subof from shop inner join shop_cat on shop.catid = shop_cat.id where shop.active='1' order by shop_cat.catname, shop.name
```

Now this results everything i need but I need to loop through the result and do another sql query for the subof value (which is a value, the value being a ID number of the shop_cat). I need to pull the catname of the subof value #, then update the result/array field subof to the name of the cat.

So if the original query gave me a value of 15 for subof, it would do a select catname from shop.cat where id='15' i would take the catname from that query and then update subof = catname for every value in the original result that has a subof value.

EDIT 3/23/13 12:30pm MST:  Using more of the code that Opeyemi wrote, to explain more of what I need.  I am not sure how else to explain it...

```
$q = "select shop.id, shop.catid, shop.name, shop_cat.catname, shop_cat.subof from shop inner join shop_cat on shop.catid = shop_cat.id where shop.active='1' order by shop_cat.catname, shop.name";
$r = mysql_query();
while(list($shopid, $catid, $name, $catname, $subof) = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
    $getname = mysql_query("select catname from shop_cat where id='$subof'");
    $rowname = mysql_fetch_assoc($getname);
    //code to update array to change value of $subof to new $rowname['catname']
}
```

The DB query runs, gets me my values.

I then need to run a loop of some kind, which will loop through every result PHP aquired from the query. This loop will take the subof value (which is a integer ID number) then run a query to get the value catname of that integer value.  Then the loop will update the current result and change the subof value from the integer to the catname pulled from the DB in the loop.

I do not need to update the database at anytime, I need to update the result/array from the first query.

Comment: John, you haven't explained your problem very clearly. The query you posted gives the values of *subof* and *catname* for all shop_id. What do you want to do next ?

Comment: Yes. Sorry if I wasn't clear. I want to take query and then loop trough the query results using php. For each result row grab the subof value. Then do a select MySQL query to get the name of the subof value from the database. Then update th array I am looping through to either update the subof that was just read with the name (replacing the id value) or make a new entry in that row of the array we just looped through and set the value from the MySQL query in the loop.

Comment: I updated my post, to try to be more defined on what I need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to store the resultset in an array and replace within the array.

```
$q = "select shop.id, shop.catid, shop.name, shop_cat.catname, shop_cat.subof from shop inner join shop_cat on shop.catid = shop_cat.id where shop.active='1' order by shop_cat.catname, shop.name";
$r = mysql_query();
$dataset = array();
// Store result in an array
while($assoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) {
  $dataset[] = $assoc;
}
// Update array
foreach($dataset as $data) {
  $getname = mysql_query("select catname from shop_cat where id='{$data['subof']}'");
  $rowname = mysql_fetch_assoc($getname);
  // replace data
  replace_dataset($data['subof'], $rowname);
}

function replace_dataset($key, $newname) {
  global $dataset;
  foreach($dataset as $k => $data) {
    if ($data['id'] == $key)
      $dataset[$k]['subof'] = $newname;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to do this in PHP or what? If you are looking for how to loop results in PHP it is as simple as this

```
$q = "select shop.id, shop.catid, shop.name, shop_cat.catname, shop_cat.subof from shop inner join shop_cat on shop.catid = shop_cat.id where shop.active='1' order by shop_cat.catname, shop.name";
$r = mysql_query();
while(list($shopid, $catid, $name, $catname, $subof) = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
  // the values from the query are assigned to the variables
  // $shopid, $catid, $name, $catname, $subof in that order already
  mysql_query("update shop_cat set subof=catname where id='$subof'");
  // My interpretation of your query can be wrong though
  // But you should get the idea
}
```

Comment: Yes, in PHP.  But I am not looking to update the shop_cat database itself.  The query array from the mysql_query of $r.  It will have a field of subof with a ID #.  I need to loop through the array, and with each loop, pull the subof value, query a select catname where id=subofvalue, get that catname and then update the original array (not the database).  Database should never get updated during this process, just the original array result from the first database query.

Comment: Opeyemi, is there a way to modify this to do what I need (check my edited post above)

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql_fetch_assoc() or mysql_fetch_array() or mysql_fetch_row() functions to fetch the row and can put your looping concept on it.

After that you can use mysql_fetch_field() to fetch field subof and id from it.

and update the database after that

You can check the following links

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-field.php

I hope you get some idea.

Comment: Please **do not** recommend the `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated and will be removed in a later version of PHP

Comment: ok. thanks for the information. Its been a year since i last used php. Not in touch with it. Anyways thanks @Bojangles

Comment: Hi Bojangles, can you elaborate more on this not recommending mysql_query functions? How should it be handled?